# Yen's K-shortest Algorithm Python Implementation - For a 10-node all-connected graph, the maximum k I could reach is below what I expected

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I've implemented Yen's K-shortest path algorithm based on the pseudocode on Wikipedia and a few open-source codes on GitHub (https://gist.github.com/ALenfant/5491853 and https://github.com/Pent00/YenKSP). The only thing I did differently was instead of removing (i, i+1) edges completely, I changed the length of the edge to infinity (which is equivalent to removing the edges in essense I guess?)

I tested my code with a 10-node graph where all nodes are connected to each other. I expected the maximum number of loop-less routes I could generate is above 100 thousands but it turns out that my code could only find up to the 9th shortest route. Is this a limitation of Yen's?

Following is my code and the 10-node sample data.

```
def yen(nodes, distances, start, end, max_k):
# Dictionary "solspace" stores actual k-shortest paths, the first of which comes from Dijkstra's algorithm.
solspace = {}
potentialsolspace = []
selected = []
# Adding the Dijkstra's shortest path into solspace dictionary
solspace[0] = (dijkstra(nodes, distances, start, end))[0]
# max_k is the specified number of shortest paths you want to find
max_k = max_k

# Looping from k = 1 to k = max_K and the 0 to (size of previous entry of solspace)-1
# Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm

for k in range(1, max_k):
    #distances = copy.deepcopy(actual_distances)
    for i in range(0, (len(solspace[k - 1]) - 1)):
        spur_node = solspace[k - 1][i]
        spur_node_plus_one = solspace[k - 1][i + 1]
        root_path = solspace[k - 1][0:i + 1]

        for shortPath in solspace:

            path_root_path = (solspace[shortPath])[0:i + 1]
            #print(path_root_path)
            if root_path == path_root_path and (len(solspace[shortPath]) - 1 > i):
                # make each overlapping edges of root path and path_root_path infinity, hence impossible to select
                distances[spur_node][spur_node_plus_one] = float('inf')
                distances[spur_node_plus_one][spur_node] = float('inf')

                # Call Dijkstra function to compute spur path (the shortest path between spur node
                # and end ignoring the i,i+1 edge
                spur_path_a = dijkstra(nodes, distances, spur_node, end)
                spur_path = spur_path_a[0]
                # Restore actual dist to distances nested dictionary
                # Total path is just the combination of root path & spur path
                total_path_tempo = root_path + spur_path
                total_path = []
                # This removes duplicates nodes but note that this is O(n^2) computing time, not efficient
                # Ref: Stack Overflow questions:480214
                [total_path.append(item) for item in total_path_tempo if item not in total_path]
                print(total_path)
                # build up potentialsolspace by adding in total path which are yet found in solspace or Potential
                # hence, the use of nested if
                if total_path not in solspace.values():
                    if [total_path, cost_path(total_path, distances)] not in potentialsolspace[:]:
                        potentialsolspace.append([total_path, cost_path(total_path, distances)])

                distances = copy.deepcopy(actual_distances)
    # This handles the case of there being no spur paths, or no spur paths left.
    # This could happen if the spur paths have already been exhausted (added to A),
    # or there are no spur paths at all such as when both the source and sink vertices lie along a "dead end".
    if len(potentialsolspace) is 0:
        break
    wcg = min(potentialsolspace, key=lambda x: x[1])
    # remove selected potential shortest path from the potential solspace
    potentialsolspace.remove(wcg)
    # Attach minimum of potentialSolSpace into solspace dictionary
    solspace[k] = wcg[0]

return solspace
```

Following is the 10-node example arranged in Python nested distionary format. Primary keys are origins while secondary keys are neighbors of primary keys. Values equal the distance between primary key and secondary key.

```
{'A': {'C': 4.0, 'B': 10.0, 'E': 10.0, 'D': 10.0, 'G': 1.0, 'F': 2.0, 'I': 3.0, 'H': 3.0, 'J': 10.0}, 'C': {'A': 4.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 9.0, 'D': 6.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 10.0, 'I': 5.0, 'H': 10.0, 'J': 5.0}, 'B': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 10.0, 'E': 8.0, 'D': 1.0, 'G': 8.0, 'F': 4.0, 'I': 2.0, 'H': 2.0, 'J': 6.0}, 'E': {'A': 9.0, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 10.0, 'D': 4.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 9.0, 'I': 3.0, 'H': 3.0, 'J': 7.0}, 'D': {'A': 4.0, 'C': 6.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 7.0, 'G': 1.0, 'F': 1.0, 'I': 2.0, 'H': 9.0, 'J': 3.0}, 
'G': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 10.0, 'B': 3.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 10.0, 'F': 5.0, 'I': 5.0, 'H': 6.0, 'J': 1.0}, 'F': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 3.0, 'B': 6.0, 'E': 7.0, 'D': 8.0, 'G': 10.0, 'I': 1.0, 'H': 8.0, 'J': 2.0}, 'I': {'A': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'B': 2.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 6.0, 'G': 7.0, 'F': 1.0, 'H': 6.0, 'J': 2.0}, 
'H': {'A': 3.0, 'C': 4.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 2.0, 'G': 6.0, 'F': 4.0, 'I': 1.0, 'J': 4.0}, 
'J': {'A': 5.0, 'C': 6.0, 'B': 1.0, 'E': 8.0, 'D': 7.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 8.0, 'I': 10.0, 'H': 1.0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this part:

```
        for shortPath in solspace:
            path_root_path = (solspace[shortPath])[0:i + 1]
            #print(path_root_path)
            if root_path == path_root_path and (len(solspace[shortPath]) - 1 > i):
                # make each overlapping edges of root path and path_root_path infinity, hence impossible to select
                distances[spur_node][spur_node_plus_one] = float('inf')
                distances[spur_node_plus_one][spur_node] = float('inf')

                # Call Dijkstra function to compute spur path (the shortest path between spur node
                # and end ignoring the i,i+1 edge
                spur_path_a = dijkstra(nodes, distances, spur_node, end)
```

Compare this to wikipedia:

```
          for each path p in A:
               if rootPath == p.nodes(0, i):
                   // Remove the links that are part of the previous shortest paths which share the same root path.
                   remove p.edge(i, i + 1) from Graph;

           for each node rootPathNode in rootPath except spurNode:
               remove rootPathNode from Graph;

           // Calculate the spur path from the spur node to the sink.
           spurPath = Dijkstra(Graph, spurNode, sink);
```

You are meant to loop over paths in A and remove lots of edges from the graph before running Dijkstra.

However, in your code you call Dijkstra from within the loop that should be removing edges, therefore you will only ever run Dijkstra on a graph with a single edge removed and this limits the number of alternative routes you can find.

Try reducing the indent by 2 tab stops on the part that calls Dijkstra.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You're right. Another cause of the problem is that, I removed the wrong (i, i+1) edge. I should have removed the (i, i+1) edge of path p in A instead of those in rootPath.